# How to recognise different csv encodings?

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I am not sure if it's with the encoding itself however this is my problem;

```
import csv

with open('vocabulary.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

I would expect it to print this:

[image: screenshot]

However it does not recognise any of the Japanese characters and rather comes up with

```
['1', '\x1b$B0l$D\x1b(B', '\x1b$B$R$H$D\x1b(B', 'one']
['2', '\x1b$BFs$D\x1b(B', '\x1b$B$U$?$D\x1b(B', 'two']
['3', '\x1b$B1_\x1b(B', '\x1b$B$($s\x1b(B', 'yen']
['4', '\x1b$B6b\x1b(B', '\x1b$B$+$M\x1b(B', 'money']
['5', '\x1b$B$3$l\x1b(B', '\x1b$B$3$l\x1b(B', 'this']
['6', '\x1b$B?eMKF|\x1b(B', '\x1b$B$9$$$h$&$S\x1b(B', 'Wednesday']
['7', '\x1b$B$"$l\x1b(B', '\x1b$B$"$l\x1b(B', 'that']
['8', '\x1b$B@h\x1b(B', '\x1b$B$5$-\x1b(B', 'ahead']
```

The encoding I used on the csv file was ISO2022. My question is, is there a way to make this appear properly?

Comment: `open` takes also a `encoding` argument. Really: you should always put the encoding explicitly.

Comment: Try, `with open('vocabulary.csv', 'r', encoding='ISO2022')`

Comment: works perfectly fine, didnt realise you could speciy an encoding argument, thank youu

Comment: Note that hardcoding an encoding **isn't** the same thing as _recognizing_ which one it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = open('vocabulary.csv', 'r', encoding='ISO2022')
```

or try

```
line.decode('ISO-2022-JP')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: And are you sure about your second solution? In that case, I think you should open as `'rb'`, or Python will tray to decode, and you cannot decode twice.